# Axios error 404, when trying to use stripe payments with react

Tags: reactjs, axios, stripe-payments

Following a tutorial ( found here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w1oLdAPyuok&t=1596s&ab_channel=StripeDevelopers ) to process stripe payments on react. However my axios post, which is exactly the same as in the video, does not work.

```
const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("api/payment_intents", {
            amount: this.state.amount * 100
          });
```

I have also tried added base url to the post

```
const { data: clientSecret } = await axios.post("http://localhost:3000/api/payment_intents", {
            amount: this.state.amount * 100
          });
```

But that doesnt work either.

Is this an issue with where the api/payment_intents is? Is there something special i need to do while on a dev server to allow for api post? The error i get is that the url is not found, error 404

Comment: what is the error code that you are getting back as a response?

Comment: I edited the post, its an error 404 not found @Michael

Comment: @cbm3333, Hi glad to see you're finding the video useful. Could you try cloning the repository from: https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js, running npm/yarn install followed by `npm run dev`? You'll also need to add your publishable/secret key to the `.env` file. I just testing things out locally and that should run for you. Currently that axios request is structured like this in the code (for your reference): https://github.com/tmarek-stripe/demo-react-stripe-js/blob/master/components/CheckoutForm.jsx#L56